# Converting Relative Paths to Absolute Paths

Tags: java, path

I have an absolute path to file A.

I have a relative path to file B from file A's directory.  This path may and will use ".." to go up the directory structure in arbitrarily complex ways.

Example A:

- `C:\projects\project1\module7\submodule5\fileA`

Example Bs:

- `..\..\module3\submodule9\subsubmodule32\fileB`
- `..\submodule5\fileB`
- `..\..\module7\..\module4\submodule1\fileB`
- `fileB`

How do I combine the two in order to get **the simplest possible** absolute path to file B?

Comment: **tl;dr answer:** new File("my/path").getCanonicalPath()

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If I get your problem right, you could do something like this:

```
File a = new File("/some/abs/path");
File parentFolder = new File(a.getParent());
File b = new File(parentFolder, "../some/relative/path");
String absolute = b.getCanonicalPath(); // may throw IOException
```

Comment: But the absolute path can have ..'s in it if I do that.  I don't want those.  Is there a way to get rid of them from the resulting absolute path?

Comment: @Tom: Using `getCanonicalPath()` instead of `getAbsolutePath()` is probably what you're looking for, in that case.

Answer (score 27):

```java
String absolutePath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(mayBeRelativePath).normalize().toAbsolutePath().toString();
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are doing here?

Comment: `FileSystems.getDefault()` gets default file system. For this file system convert a `mayBeRelativePath` string to a `Path` object. `normalize()` it, that is remove constructions like `../abc/../` from any parts of the path. Transform `toAbsolutePath()` if it is not an absolute yet and get the path as a string.

Comment: @rssdev10  Thanks a bunch, 
this worked great  in my testing and is only a single line in comparison to all other answers containing 3-20 lines for the same thing.

Comment: Looks great but Java doesn't see FileSystems as an import.

Comment: @Andrew FileSystems are available only from Java 7 & above

Answer (score 15):

In **Java 7** you can also use the [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) interface:

```
Path basePath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\projects\\project1\\module7\\submodule5\\fileA");
Path resolvedPath = basePath.getParent().resolve("..\\..\\module3\\submodule9\\subsubmodule32\\fileB"); // use getParent() if basePath is a file (not a directory) 
Path abolutePath = resolvedPath.normalize();
```

Comment: Good answer, but you need to replace those `\ ` with `\\ ` or it won't compile

Answer (score 5):

> From your question, if i could get it right, you are looking to get abolute path from relative path, then you can do following.

```
File b = new File("../some/relative/path");
String absolute = b.getCanonicalPath(); // may throw IOException
```

or shorthand notation can be,

```
String absolute = new File("../some/relative/path").getCanonicalPath();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [`FilenameUtils.normalize()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#normalize(java.lang.String)) from Apache [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

Comment: why add external dependencies when standard Java NIO does the job?

Answer (score 1):

What's better than just creating a utility that converts relative paths to absolute paths is to create a utility that converts any path passed to it into an absolute path so that you don't have to check on the client-side.

The below code works for me in both cases and I've used the `String` type at the signature of the method (both parameter and return value):

```
public static String toAbsolutePath(String maybeRelative) {
    Path path = Paths.get(maybeRelative);
    Path effectivePath = path;
    if (!path.isAbsolute()) {
        Path base = Paths.get("");
        effectivePath = base.resolve(path).toAbsolutePath();
    }
    return effectivePath.normalize().toString();
}
```

Changing the above code to expose `Path` types on the signature of the method is trivial (and actually easier) but I think that using `String` on the signature gives more flexibility.

Comment: What’s the difference to just calling `path.toAbsolutePath().normalize()`?

Comment: @QuirinF.Schroll sorry, no longer working with Java...

Answer (score 0):

I know it isn't the best solution but can't you just combine the substring of fileA's path from 0 to the `lastIndexOf("\")` with fileB's path.

Example A:

- `C:\projects\project1\module7\submodule5\fileA`

Example Bs:

- `..\..\module3\submodule9\subsubmodule32\fileB`

`C:\projects\project1\module7\submodule5\..\..\module3\submodule9\subsubmodule32\fileB`

If you don't want the `..` in there then, it would take longer, but I recommend going through the path for `fileB` and keep taking the substring from 0 to the first index of `\`. Then check the substring. If it is `..` then remove the substring from there and remove the substring from `fileA's` path from `lastIndexOf(\)` to length. Then repeat. That way you are removing the folders you don't need and the `..s`.

So :

Example A:

- `C:\projects\project1\module7\submodule5\fileA`

Example Bs:

- `..\..\module3\submodule9\subsubmodule32\fileB`

  --> `C:\projects\project1\module3\submodule9\subsubmodule32\fileB`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code that works for me.

```
 public String absolutePath(String relative, String absoluteTo)
    {       
        String[] absoluteDirectories = relative.split("\\\\");
        String[] relativeDirectories = absoluteTo.split("\\\\");
        int relativeLength = relativeDirectories.length;
        int absoluteLength = absoluteDirectories.length; 
        int lastCommonRoot = 0;
        int index;
        for (index = 0; index < relativeLength; index++)
            if (relativeDirectories[index].equals("..\\\\"))
                lastCommonRoot = index;
            else
                break;
        StringBuilder absolutePath = new StringBuilder();
        for (index = 0; index < absoluteLength - lastCommonRoot; index++)
        {  
             if (absoluteDirectories[index].length() > 0) 
                 absolutePath.append(absoluteDirectories[index] + "\\\\");                          
        }
        for (index = lastCommonRoot; index < relativeLength  - lastCommonRoot; 
                                                               index++)
        {  
             if (relativeDirectories[index].length() > 0) 
                 absolutePath.append(relativeDirectories[index] + "\\\\");                          
        }
        return absolutePath.toString();              
    }
```

Also I the conversion to relative:

```
public String relativePath(String absolute, String relativeTo) throws Exception
    {       
        String[] absoluteDirectories = absolute.split("\\\\");
        String[] relativeDirectories = relativeTo.split("\\\\");
        int length = absoluteDirectories.length < relativeDirectories.length ?
                        absoluteDirectories.length : relativeDirectories.length;
        int lastCommonRoot = -1;
        int index;
        for (index = 0; index < length; index++)
            if (absoluteDirectories[index].equals(relativeDirectories[index]))
                lastCommonRoot = index;
            else
                break;
        if (lastCommonRoot > -1){
            StringBuilder relativePath = new StringBuilder();
            for (index = lastCommonRoot + 1; index <absoluteDirectories.length;
                                                                         index++)
                if (absoluteDirectories[index].length() > 0)
                    relativePath.append("..\\\\");
            for (index = lastCommonRoot + 1; index <relativeDirectories.length-1;
                                                                         index++)
                relativePath.append(relativeDirectories[index] + "\\\\");
            relativePath.append(relativeDirectories[relativeDirectories.length - 1]);
            return relativePath.toString();         
        }
        else{
            throw new Exception("No common root found between working direcotry and filename");
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Windows path to full Java path.

```
String winPath = downloadPath+"\\"+dir_contents[i].getName();
String absPath = winPath.replace("\\","\\\\");
```