# JavaFX File Doesn't Exist Exception Despite File Being In Correct Location

Tags: file, exception, javafx, import, stl

[image]As you can see here the file is clearly available in the project in a source folder, however when running the program I am receiving an file does not exist exception. Below I have posted the full error:

```
com.interactivemesh.jfx.importer.ImportException: StlMeshImporter read(File file) : file doesn't exist !
at com.interactivemesh.jfx.importer.stl.StlMeshImporterImpl.read(Unknown Source)
at com.interactivemesh.jfx.importer.stl.StlMeshImporter.read(Unknown Source)
at minimalist.TriangleMeshTest.start(TriangleMeshTest.java:30)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Note the difference between absolute and relative paths. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896840/relative-to-absolute-path-in-java  and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204955/converting-relative-paths-to-absolute-paths/3205019#3205019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an absolute path. If you want to use an absolute path, you need to provide the full path from root (/ or C:/)

If You want to use a relative path `music/untitled.stl` you need have the current working directory pointing to the Test folder.

One way to go about loading resources from code is to put the resources in a `resource` folder inside the `src` folder and then to use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resource/resource_name")`.

So, if you were to move your music folder in the src folder you would be able to read the file like:

`getClass().getResourceAsStream("/music/untitled.stl");`

Note how you use a "/" here at the beginning. It works in this case because getResourceAsStream takes of care of resolving the path to your src directory using the ClassLoader.

Comment: `File file = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/music/mapTest3.stl").toExternalForm());
      stlImporter.read(file);` I attempted using this however, I am receiving a null pointer exception. May you provide a full code snippet below in your answer?

Comment: Did you move the music folder inside the src folder? next to the minimalist folder in your project. I tested on my end with this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resource/test.txt") , where resource is in my src folder, and I got a valid **Stream**. 
If you want to use a **File rather than a Stream**, then use getClass().getResource("/music/mapTest3.stl").getFile()); You can also take a look here for an example: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

Comment: music is a resource folder and the way Eclipse is organized you don't have resource folders inside the src folder, rather alongside it.

Comment: Managed to get it to work by using `stlImporter.read(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/music/mapTest3.stl"));` that line, however I know that will not work when I export it to a `jar` file.

Comment: Oh got it just needed to do `stlImporter.read(this.getClass().getResource("/mapTest3.stl"));`

Comment: Well done Adam,  sorry I wasnt aware of that for eclipse.  Yes if that is a resource folder than you can omit the name when using getResource