# JAVA - Make SSL call with keystore into webservice inside AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, keystore, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a webservice Java loaded in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
This webservice make SSL rest call using jks keystore.
When I execute the webservice on my machine, I load keystore with

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "c:\...\file.jks"); 
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "c:\...\file.jks"); 
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "sviluppo");
```

With System.setProperty **I need absolute path of file.jks**.
How Can I make the same on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

*(I tried with getAbsolutePath() and getCanonicalPath() but, on my machine, these istructions return myEclipse root)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answer.
I solve it in this way: first I put my jks file in a project package "package" with client "Test".
Inside my code I wrote:

```
String pathKeyStore = package.Test.class.getResource("file.jks").getPath();
pathKeyStore = pathResourceKeyStore.replaceAll("%20", " ");

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", pathKeyStore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", pathKeyStore); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
```

And it works also in AWS Elastic Beanstalk!

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to bundle your `file.jks` with your java application (WAR or JAR) then you can get the absolute path from the relative path of `file.jks` as describe in this accepted answer: [Converting Relative Paths to Absolute Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204955/converting-relative-paths-to-absolute-paths)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in the comment there is my solution that works with AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: OK great. if the answer gave you any hint or help you can mark it as helpful by clicking the up arrow.

Comment: Done! :) Thank u